# Missing state cookie in next-auth next js 13 when using GoogleProvider

Tags: next.js, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, next-auth

To cause this error, I sign into my application successfully using google, then press the back button in my browser to redirect me back to the google login page. When I login again into the same account or another account the error specified in the title occurs.

My main thought was to remove the google sign in page from the browser history but that seems a bit weird, I would rather the user gets redirected to an error page if they try to go back to the sign in page when they're already authenticated.

Here is my auth.ts code:

```
import { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth"
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google"
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials"
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client"
import bcrypt from "bcrypt"

const prisma = new PrismaClient()

export const authConfig: NextAuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID as string,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET as string,
      authorization: {
        params: {},
      },
    }),
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "Credentials",
      credentials: {
        name: { label: "Name", type: "text" },
        email: { label: "Email", type: "email" },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password" },
      },
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        const { name, email, password } = credentials as User
        if (req.body?.callbackUrl.includes("login")) {
          const user = await prisma.user.findFirst({
            where: { email },
          })
          if (user && (await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password))) {
            return user
          } else {
            throw new Error("404")
          }
        } else {
          return await prisma.user
            .create({
              data: {
                name,
                email,
                password: await bcrypt.hash(password, 10),
                loginType: "credentials",
              },
            })
            .catch(() => {
              throw new Error("404")
            })
        }
      },
    }),
  ],
  pages: {
    signIn: "/",
    signOut: "/",
  },
  callbacks: {
    async session({ token, session }) {
      if (token) {
        session.user.role = token.role
      }
      return session
    },
    async jwt({ token, account }) {
      const dbUser = await prisma.user.findFirst({
        where: {
          email: token.email as string,
        },
      })
      if (!dbUser) {
        await prisma.user.create({
          data: {
            name: token.name as string,
            email: token.email as string,
            loginType: account?.provider as string,
            password: "null",
          },
        })
        return token
      }
      return {
        name: dbUser.name,
        email: dbUser.email,
        role: dbUser.role,
      }
    },
  },
}
```

Comment: Hi, could please edit to include a more detailed error message? Your issue seems similar to this https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/7329. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Looks like ongoing issue described [here](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/discussions/7491)
There is also a [workaround](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/discussions/7491#discussioncomment-6166539). You can try to disable checks for GoogleProvider:

```
GoogleProvider({
  clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID as string,
  clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET as string,
  authorization: {
    params: {},
  },
  checks: ['none'],
})
```

But it will make GoogleProvider less secure.